# spring integration tcp-out-bound exception

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration, tcpclient

We are using Spring integration 4.1.3.

Implemented the client using tcp-outbound-gateway.

A tcp rset packet was received from the server during the request and an exception occurred.
What is the reason?
Thank you.

```
    // interface
    public interface TcpSendGateway {
        public byte[] send(String text);
    } 
    // send
    byte[] response = sendGateway.send(request);




    <int:gateway id="gw"
                 service-interface="com.mainpay.service.TcpSendGateway"
                 default-request-channel="input"
                 default-reply-channel="reply"/>

    <int-tcp:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
                                    type="client"
                                    host="#{prop['app.cultureland.host']}"
                                    port="#{prop['app.cultureland.port']}"
                                    so-timeout="10000"
                                    single-use="false"
                                    so-keep-alive="true"
    />                         
    <int:channel id="input" />
    <int-tcp:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway" 
                                  request-channel="input"
                                  reply-channel="reply"
                                  connection-factory="client"
                                  request-timeout="10000"                                      
                                  reply-timeout="10000"                                                                                                               
                                  />        
    <int:channel id="reply" datatype="java.lang.String" />
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
▶ 17.09.29 17:07:37 [pool-2-thread-2] ERROR o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Read exception 211.59.10.133:7611:51503:d2ec0199-fd15-49c0-bd99-0d864eb2145b SocketException:Connection reset
▶ 17.09.29 17:07:39 [http-nio-19900-exec-5] ERROR o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Tcp Gateway exception
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception while awaiting reply; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway$AsyncReply.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:288)
```

**wireshark log**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGnGC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be sure that your client and server are agreed with the (de)serialization protocol. See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories) for more info:

> TCP is a streaming protocol; this means that some structure has to be provided to data transported over TCP, so the receiver can demarcate the data into discrete messages. Connection factories are configured to use (de)serializers to convert between the message payload and the bits that are sent over TCP.

The default one is the `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer` which deals with the `\r\n` message delimiter.

So, your client may receive the package but since it doesn't meet the proper delimiter it fails waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Means the server forced the socket closed (`RST`) for some reason. You need to look at the server logs.

Perhaps it's not expecting the default wire format (text terminated by `CRLF` - `0x0d0a`).

Comment: Thank you so much. you really helped me a lot